# Unable to fecth all user details using Microsoft Graph api graphServiceClient.Users.Request() C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am running below code :

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace MSGraphAPI
{
    class Program
    {


        private static string clientId = "XXXXX";


        private static string tenantID = "XXXX";


        private static string objectId = "XXXX";


        private static string clientSecret = "XXXX";

        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {




            //     IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            //.Create(clientId)
            //.WithTenantId(tenantID)
            //.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            //.Build();

            //        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            //        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            //        var users = await graphClient.Users
            //            .Request()
            //            .GetAsync();


            var tenantId = "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com";

            // The client ID of the app registered in Azure AD
            var clientId = "XXXX";

            // *Never* include client secrets in source code!
            var clientSecret = "XXXX"; // Or some other secure place.

            // The app registration should be configured to require access to permissions
            // sufficient for the Microsoft Graph API calls the app will be making, and
            // those permissions should be granted by a tenant administrator.
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            // Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
            // which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
            // and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

        // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
        var authResult = await confidentialClient
            .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                );

            // Make a Microsoft Graph API query
            var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(users.ToString());

            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage userss = graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            foreach (User user in userss)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found user: " + user.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting only 100 users ( when i use debug and check the count and also put a watch on this variable)  in the userss variable  , but total number of users is around 1000 . I want to fetch all user details and also want to fetch users based on specific criteria using select or any other api in the same code.

Please help me.

Comment: You've already asked a very similar question earlier today - [Microsoft Graph api code in C# displays only limited number of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282929/microsoft-graph-api-code-in-c-sharp-displays-only-limited-number-of-users).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Current code uses graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync() ,but the link which you have provided use  uri , first uri is constructed and then call is made           var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999"; how to implement the similar logic here.

Comment: You're asking the same question with two different code samples, but this doesn't change the answer. They're both calling the same API endpoints.

Comment: Yes, but how to put the limit ,similar to $top=999 in this case , i am trying something like graphServiceClient.UsersRequest().GetAsync().Result.limit  ,but it has no similar member .

Comment: Please see the answer I posted to your previous question. You shouldn't set `$top=999`, you need to pull down each page of data. Extremely large requests like that are much slower, can trigger throttling, and are extremely prone to network errors.

Comment: Ok, i am trying  userss.NextPageRequest to fetch more pages.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works to show all user details.

```
      do
            {
                foreach (User user in users)
                {

               if (user.Mail != null)
               {
                    if (user.Mail.Contains("Tom"))
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("Hurray");
                    }
                }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id}");
                    Flag++;
                }
            }
            while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
```