# How to fetch values from jToken while looping through json data

Tags: c#, json

I have below  json data :

```
  {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999&$skiptoken=X%27445370740200010000001B3A6461726C61682E6469736D756B657340646974726F6C2E636F6D29XXXXXXD396339312D343134362D393833322D346537366430363033356563B900000000000000000000%27",
    "value": [{
        "businessPhones": [999999],
        "displayName": "___XXXXX_Conv_SA___",
        "givenName": null,
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": null,
        "userPrincipalName": "__XXXXX_Conv_SA___@company.onmicrosoft.com",
        "id": "e7dc80e8-482d-4020-bb81-eee9458f5a37"
    }, {
        "businessPhones": [9197883],
        "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
        "givenName": null,
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": "_XXXXX_BXXXXS@company.com",
        "mobilePhone": 99983333,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": null,
        "userPrincipalName": "_XXXX_BACCHUS@company.onmicrosoft.com",
        "id": "0f8dc1ee-0bf3-497a-ad95-33"
    }]
}
```

I am fetching JSON data in json string  as below.

```cs
GraphUsers= (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

JToken userData = null;

foreach (var pair in GraphUsers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
    if (pair.Key.Equals("value"))
    {
        //just fetch any random value from array
        JToken jToken = pair.Value[3];
        userData = jToken;
        Console.WriteLine(userData);
    }
}
```

Now, when `pair.Key.Equals("value")` in the loop, the data is like below:

```
{[
  {
    "businessPhones": [XXXXXXX],
    "displayName": "___VMware_Conv_SA___",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": XXXXX,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "___VXXX___@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "e7dc80e8-482d-4020-bb81-eee9458f5a37"
  },
  {
    "businessPhones": [XXXX],
    "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "_IUSR_BACCHUS@XXXXX.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "_XXXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "0f8dc1ee-0bf3-497a-ad95-d3935beee515"
  },
  {
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "_XXX@XXXXX.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "_XXXXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "37981ed8-7b9a-4883-a300-f7d9b4b7fca2"
  },
  {
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "_IUSR_XXX@XXXXX.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "_XXXXR@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "43ac2c00-663b-4ae3-b3a6-7a9a74e89a12"
  },
  {
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "XXXXXX@XXXX.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": "_IUSR_XXX@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "b5937f36-e2e5-4687-83ca-9640b2679e0c"
  },
]}
```

`userData` has below value and format:

```
{
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "Internet Guest Account",
  "givenName": null,
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": "_IUSR_XXX@XXXXX.com",
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "surname": null,
  "userPrincipalName": "_XXXXR@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
  "id": "43ac2c00-663b-4ae3-b3a6-7a9a74e89a12"
}
```

I want to fetch and check `businessPhones`, `displayName`, etc. in each loop from this when `pair.Key.Equals("value")` and from `userData` variable. 
Attached is the debug watch of the JSON data at specific point.

I also tried converting `userData` to Dictionary as below.

```cs
linkDictionary= userData.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you send chat request.

Comment: @AllTech can you post GraphUsers class ?

Comment: @Mr.AF GraphUsers is JObject GraphUsers;

Comment: I also tried converting userData  to Dictionary.

Comment: You can use the `JObject` indexer [`Item[String]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) to access the value of `"value"` without needing to loop, like so:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/AevK2x.  `foreach (var obj in GraphUsers["value"]) { var displayName = (string)obj["displayName"]; var phones = obj["businessPhones"].ToObject<string []>(); }`  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** Create `jsonModel` equal to your `jsonFormat`

```
public class jsonModel
        {
            public string @odata_context { get; set; }
            public string @odata_nextLink { get; set; }
            public List<valueModel> value { get; set; }
        }
```

**2-** Create `valueModel` equal to `jsonValueFormat`

```
public class valueModel
        {
            public List<string> businessPhones { get; set; }
            public string displayName { get; set; }
            public string givenName { get; set; }
            public string jobTitle { get; set; }
            public string mail { get; set; }
            public string mobilePhone { get; set; }
            public string officeLocation { get; set; }
            public string preferredLanguage { get; set; }
            public string surname { get; set; }
            public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
```

**3-** DeserializeObject from `jsonString` to `JsonModel`

```
jsonModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonModel>(json);
```

### Complete Example

```
namespace ConsoleAppForTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{" +
                          "\"@odata_context\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users\"," +
                          "\"@odata_nextLink\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999&$skiptoken=\"," +
                          "\"value\": [{" +
                             "\"businessPhones\": [999999]," +
                             "\"displayName\": \"___XXXXX_Conv_SA___\"," +
                             "\"givenName\": null," +
                             "\"jobTitle\": null," +
                             "\"mail\": null," +
                             "\"mobilePhone\": null," +
                             "\"officeLocation\": null," +
                             "\"preferredLanguage\": null," +
                             "\"surname\": null," +
                             "\"userPrincipalName\": \"__XXXXX_Conv_SA___@company.onmicrosoft.com\"," +
                             "\"id\": \"e7dc80e8-482d-4020-bb81-eee9458f5a37\"" +
                          "}]" +
                      "}";
            jsonModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonModel>(json);
            foreach (valueModel i in data.value.ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Complete Value object");
                Console.WriteLine("--------START---------");
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i));
                Console.WriteLine("---------END----------");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("get value by property name");
                Console.WriteLine("=> businessPhones:" + i.businessPhones[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("=> displayName:" + i.displayName);
                Console.WriteLine("=> givenName:" + i.givenName);
                Console.WriteLine("=> jobTitle:" + i.jobTitle);
                Console.WriteLine("=> mail:" + i.mail);
                Console.WriteLine("=> and so on");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public class jsonModel
        {
            public string @odata_context { get; set; }
            public string @odata_nextLink { get; set; }
            public List<valueModel> value { get; set; }
        }
        public class valueModel
        {
            public List<string> businessPhones { get; set; }
            public string displayName { get; set; }
            public string givenName { get; set; }
            public string jobTitle { get; set; }
            public string mail { get; set; }
            public string mobilePhone { get; set; }
            public string officeLocation { get; set; }
            public string preferredLanguage { get; set; }
            public string surname { get; set; }
            public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Complete Value object
--------START---------
{"businessPhones":["999999"],"displayName":"___XXXXX_Conv_SA___","givenName":null,"jobTitle":null,"mail":null,"mobilePhone":null,"officeLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"surname":null,"userPrincipalName":"__XXXXX_Conv_SA___@company.onmicrosoft.com","id":"e7dc80e8-482d-4020-bb81-eee9458f5a37"}
---------END----------
----------------------
get value by property name
=> businessPhones:999999
=> displayName:___XXXXX_Conv_SA___
=> givenName:
=> jobTitle:
=> mail:
=> and so on
```

**NOTE:** `@odata.context` is not a valid json property name because `'.'` is not a valid char for naming. Therefore, i have replaced `'.'` to `'_'`.

Comment: @MrAF  Thanks a lot. Initially i only created  valueModel and not JsonModel.

Comment: But, how to work on @odata_nextLink to fetch next set of users.This contains only 999 users from MS Graph api.

Comment: @AllTech the example was complete you can used it for either 1 or 1000 of users no matter. there is no difference.

Comment: @AllTech just pass json string to deserializer

Comment: @AllTech your json value property is array of objects therefore as you can see i have initiated array of valueModel therefore the value array length can be 1 or 999 but in the example for simplification i considered it's 1 .

Comment: You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282929/microsoft-graph-api-code-in-c-sharp-displays-only-limited-number-of-users?noredirect=1#comment106634735_60282929